# Encryption/Decryption on string

Tags: php, string, bash, encryption

I am very new to encryption and I would really appreciate your input on this puzzle as I am stuck.

The puzzle:

```
<?php> blinker
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
```

terminal:~ A fantastic internship opportunity...

-bash: Solve this puzzle
If you’re interested then `21613@23151811.co.za = fun@work.co.za`
which will lead you to `171225.13916.co.za`

terminal:~ what is the answer$

Please note I will not be entering with the answer I am just so interested as to how to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is job.mip.co.za
Take the alphabet and associate a number to each letter.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
```

Take the word work: w=23;o=15;r=18;k=11
If you do this with the word fun it's not going to work. That's because fun is "the opposite of work". So: f=6 but you have to start counting to 6 from the end of the alphabet. So you'll get f=21. u=21 but you have to start counting from the end of the alphabet and you'll get u=6. And n will be 13.

Now you take the number 171225 and you do the same as fun. You'll get the word job.
As for the number 13916 you do the same as work and you'll get the word mip.
Now type job.mip.co.za as answer and you'll get redirected to http://job.mip.co.za/

That's it

Answer (score 1):

```
if 21613@23151811.co.za = fun@work.co.za

Then it is safe to assume that we working with a number and alphabet 
correlation where a number equals an alphabet

Mathematically speaking 1 = A, and 2 = B .... and the are only 26 alphabets meaning we can't go higher than the number 26.

The first set of numbers are 5, and "fun" has three Alphabets where the only viable combination is
[21][6][13] = [U][f][M]
[2][16][13] = [A][P][M]

but none of them equals FUN

The second set of number are 8, and "work" has four Alphabets where the only viable combination is
[23][15][18][11] = [W][O][R][K]

Which give us the hint that the first set of numbers do in fact equals the word 'Fun'
we just have to look at the numbers differently.

how can 'F' be equal to [21] 
and     'U' be equal to [6]
and     'N' be equal to [13]  

or

how can 'F' be equal to [2] 
and     'U' be equal to [16]
and     'N' be equal to [13] 

we discovered counting from the right to the left side leaves us at undesired position
now lets try counting from the left side to right and see if it leave us at the desired position

[21] from left side to right side leave me at position [F]
[6] from left side to right side leave me at position [U]
[13] from left side to right side leave me at position [N]

[2] from left side to right side leave me at position [Y]
[6] from left side to right side leave me at position [U]
[13] from left side to right side leave me at position [N]

thus the first combination equals my desired value.

now using that same method it's safe to repeat on the next set of numbers.

171225.13916.co.za

[17] from left side to right side leave me at position [J]
[12] from left side to right side leave me at position [O]
[25] from left side to right side leave me at position [B]

and second set of numbers read from right side to left side
[13][9][16] = [M][I][P]
[13][9][1][6] = [M][I][A][F]

So that leaves me with only two possibilities.

'job.mip.co.za' or 'job.miaf.co.za' only of them is takes me where I need to be... my new home. Hi :)
```

Answer (score 0):

job.mip.co.za

171225.13916.co.za

m=16;i=9;p=16

l=17;o=12;b=25
which is lob

Take the word mip: m=16;i=9;p=16,  l=12 counting to 12 from the end of the alphabet i get l=15. o-15 and counting from the end of the alphabet i get o=12 and b=25

Answer (score 0):

job.mip.co.za 171225.13916.co.za

I take the word mip where by M=13 I=9 P=16

so for Job J= 10 and counting to 10 from the end of alphabet i get j=17, for o=15 i count to 15 from the end of last alphabet i get 12, for b=2 i count to 2 from the end of last alphabet i get 25.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I did.

`21613. 23151811.co.za` wich equals to fun@work

`21 16 13=  F=21 U=6 N=14` counting from Z that's number

```
26 23 15 18 11= W=10 O=15 R=18 K=11
```

counting from A that's number 1
Then: fun@work

`171225.13916.co.za` wich equals to job.mip

`17 12 25= J= 17 O=12 B=25` counting from Z that's number

```
26 13 9 16= M=13 I=9 P=16
```

counting from A that's number 1

Answer (score 0):

```
17 12 25 = job
‘j’  ‘o’  ‘b’

13 9 16 = mip
‘m’ ‘i’ ‘p’
```

Therefore `171225.13916.co.za = job.mip.co.za`